# logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[100,4] labels_size=[400,4]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

**My conda environment**

```
Python: 3.6.10
NumPy: 1.18.1
Pandas: 0.23.4
TensorFlow: 2.2.0
```

I am using a custom generator and training a CNN 1D.

The generator takes in the list of file names and batch size as inputs and outputs data and one-hot encoded labels from the file names.

**Data**:

Data is in multiple files. Each file has 10 individual signals of length 8001 in 10 columns.

**Custom Generator to load files in Batches**

```
def tf_data_generator(file_list, batch_size = 10):
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i*batch_size >= len(file_list):  
            i = 0
            np.random.shuffle(file_list)
        else:
            file_chunk = file_list[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size] 
            data = []
            labels = []
            label_classes = tf.constant(["RS0", "Td2", "Jum","Td3"]) 
            for file in file_chunk:
                temp = pd.read_csv(open(file,'r'),header=None,index_col=False,squeeze=True)#
                sigdf=temp.str.split(expand=True,)
                sigdf=sigdf.replace('NaN',np.nan)
                sigdf=sigdf.dropna(axis=1)

                data.append(sigdf.values.reshape(10,8001,1)) 
                pattern = tf.constant(eval("file[79:-4]")) #extracting data from file name
                for j in range(len(label_classes)):
                    if re.match(pattern.numpy(), label_classes[j].numpy()): # matching pattern
                        l=[j]*len(sigdf.columns) #repeating label outputs according to the number of cols 
                        labels.extend(l)
            data = np.asarray(data).reshape(-1,8001,1)
            #one hot encoding the data
            labels = np.asarray(utils.to_categorical(labels))
            yield data, labels
            i = i + 1
```

**Code to check Generator Output**

```
num = 0
for data, labels in check_data:
    print(data.shape, labels.shape)
    #print(labels, "<--Labels")
    print()
    num = num + 1
    if num > 5: break
```

**Output**

```
(100, 8001, 1) (100, 4)

(100, 8001, 1) (100, 4)

(100, 8001, 1) (100, 4)

(100, 8001, 1) (100, 4)

(100, 8001, 1) (100, 4)

(100, 8001, 1) (100, 4)
```

Here it is showing the label outputs as `100,4` for 100 signals with one-hot encoding of 4 outputs.

**CNN Model**

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv1D(16, 3, activation = "relu", input_shape = (8001,1)),
    layers.MaxPool1D(2),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Conv1D(32, 7, activation = "relu"),
    layers.MaxPool1D(2),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Conv1D(64, 7,activation="relu"),
    layers.MaxPool1D(2),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(16, activation = "relu"),
    layers.Dense(4, activation = "softmax")
])

model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam", metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

But, When I tried to fit the model I am getting the error

```
InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[100,4] labels_size=[400,4]
     [[node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (defined at <ipython-input-105-142deaf73db1>:2) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_26061]
```

In the error, it is showing `[400,4]` as the labels size. Whereas, the generator output is showing `[100,4]`. I am not sure where I am going wrong!

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the dimension of the labels is not the same on as the dimension of the output. (see [categorical_crossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/categorical_crossentropy)).
To find out, you can either display the summary of the model to check the output shape, with: `model.summary()`. 
Or you can call the model `model(np.zeros((1, 8001, 1)))` and check the tensor's shape.

Comment: I checked `model(np.zeros((1,8001,1))`. The output is `<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]], dtype=float32)>`. So, the output is `(1,4)` as expected. Also, I checked `model.summary( )`. The output of the last layer is `(None, 4)`. And, I am sure the output of the custom generator  `<FlatMapDataset shapes: ((None, 8001, 1), (None, 4)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>` from traindataset is also `(None,4)`.  So, I couldn't understand where it is failing to debug!

Comment: Can you add all the related code ? and the full printed output of the model.fit_generator

Comment: Here's the code for compile `model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam", metrics = ["accuracy"])`  and for fit `model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data = validation_dataset, steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch, validation_steps = validation_steps, epochs = 10)` . I couldn't post entire error log in the comments, but I could post it [here](https://codeshare.io/5OEYj7).

Comment: Could you try with `model.fit_generator(tf_data_generator )` with the proper shapes and type

Comment: I got the same error message as `model.fit`  with a warning that `model.fit_generator` is deprecated

Comment: There must be more information. Could you post a working code that exhibits the issue ?